# How can i use order by date in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when i add new documents firebase collection randomly goes to middle or end of the collection list. but i want to put every new collection to the end of the list.

simply i just want to show new added musics at top of the page instead of showing randomly middle or end of the page. how can i do that?

Musics.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { getDocs, collection, deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, db } from "../../../firebase-config";
import { Modal, Button, RouteModal } from "react-bootstrap";
import Iframe from "react-iframe";
import "./Musics.css";
import MusicModal from "./MusicModal";

const Musics = () => {
  const [musicList, setMusicList] = useState([]);
  const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "music");
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getFrame = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(postsCollectionRef);
      setMusicList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    getFrame();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="music-container">
      <div className="height">
        {musicList.map((musics) => {
            let embedChange = musics.musicEmbed;
            let newEmbed = embedChange.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");

            console.log(embedChange);
            let patos = embedChange.replace(
              "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",
              ""
            );
            return (
              <div className="musics">
                <div className="music1">
                  <img
                    src={`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${patos}/mqdefault.jpg`}
                    id="music-thumb"
                  />
                  <div className="gridso">
                    <h2 id="music-title">{musics.musicTitle}</h2>
                    <div className="flexo">
                      <img src={musics.photoURL} id="music-img" />
                      <p id="music-name">{musics.name}</p>
                    </div>
                    <MusicModal
                      musicTitle={musics.musicTitle}
                      musicEmbed={newEmbed}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Musics;
```

AddMusic.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, auth } from "../../../firebase-config";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./AddMusic.css";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col, Card, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const AddMusic = ({ isAuth }) => {
  const [musicEmbed, setMusicEmbed] = useState("");
  const [musicTitle, setMusicTitle] = useState("");

  const postsCollectionRef = collection(db, "music");
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const createPost = async () => {
    await addDoc(postsCollectionRef, {
      musicTitle,
      musicEmbed,
      name: auth.currentUser.displayName,
      id: auth.currentUser.uid,

      photoURL: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
    });

    navigate("/musics");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container fluid="p-5 d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 pt-5">
        <Form>
          <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
            <Form.Label column sm={2}>
              Music Title
            </Form.Label>
            <Col sm={10}>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Music Title..."
                onChange={(e) => setMusicTitle(e.target.value)}
              />
            </Col>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group
            as={Row}
            className="mb-2"
            onChange={(e) => setMusicEmbed(e.target.value)}
          >
            <Form.Label column sm={2}>
              Music URL
            </Form.Label>
            <Col sm={10}>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Music URL (Youtube Only)"
              />
            </Col>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3">
            <Col sm={{ span: 10, offset: 2 }}>
              <Button variant="warning" onClick={createPost}>
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Col>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddMusic;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase orders your documents by ID by default.
You can query the documents ordered by some other property, like a createdAt or updatedAt.
Some docs and cookbook [can be found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

- Your `collectionRef` needs to have a `date` field (or similar)
- Then you can fetch, and order, by `date` field

---

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getFrame = async () => {
    // create query constrained by order
    const myQuery = query(postsCollectionRef, orderBy('date', 'asc'))
    // now fetch collection/document
    const data = await getDocs(myQuery);
    setMusicList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };
  getFrame();
}, []);
```